# Pregunta sobre if else statements

Tags: javascript, if, else

Simple pregunta de un novato,   no entiendo porque el 0 numérico me da par en este caso, quiero que si es `0`, `''`, `isNaN` me de `'Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido'`:

```js
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');
  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.')
  } else if(!numeroUsuario || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '0') {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: y porque no simplemente validas que si es 0 pida el numero valido?

Comment: ademas si realizas la prueba Number(!numeroUsuario) si la variable es 0, la funcion te devuelve 1

Comment: Es que el 0 es par, cumple con la condición de ser múltiplo de 2.

Comment: prompt devuelve un string, no un número o null

Comment: @fran, lo que devuelve el prompt es un String. Si le sitúas el operador not lógico delante a cualquier String te dará false (una cadena es verdadera de por sí a no ser que esté vacía), no importa si la cadena es "0".

Answer (score 2):

Te falla porque lo que devuelve prompt no es un número, sino un string:

```
Number(!'0') === 0
```

Puedes solucionarlo simplemente haciendo un parseInt:

```js
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');
  if (numeroUsuario === '') {
     alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
     continue;
  } 
  
  numeroUsuario=parseInt(numeroUsuario);
  if(isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === 0) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
 }
}
```

Por otro lado, compararlo con null tampoco te aporta nada porque prompt te devuelve una cadena vacía (`''`) si no introduces ningún valor

Comment: Ya, si entiendo lo que dices, pero si hago parse Int, luego no funcionara null, ese no lo pusiste, quiero saber exactamente lo que tu has hecho PERO con otra opcion => (numeroUsuario === null) => alert(''Por favor, introduce algún valor.'')

Comment: No es del todo así: si no metes ningún valor no tienes null, sino una cadena vacía. He actualizado la respuesta para que lo veas

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que agregarle el condicional `numeroUsuario == 0` en el `else if`

tienes que estar muy pendiente en que casos usar la comparación `===` que iguala el valor y el tipo en cambio `==` solo iguala el valor

Los operadores `===` y `!==` son los operadores de comparación estricta. Esto significa que si los operandos tienen tipos diferentes, no son iguales. Por ejemplo,

```
1 === "1" // false
1 !== "1"  // true
null === undefined // false
```

Los operadores `==` y `!=` son los operadores de comparación relajada. Es decir, si los operandos tienen tipos diferentes, JavaScript trata de convertirlos para que fueran comparables. Por ejemplo,

```
1 == "1" // true
1 != "1" // false
null == undefined // true
```

Espero te ayude saludos

```js
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');

  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
   alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.')
  } else if(Number(!numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '' ) { // si pongo !numeroUsuario || isNaN(numeroUsuario) EN EL QUE !numeroUsuario ya invalida el 0 numerico y '', porque me sale que 0 es par ???
  alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.')
 } else if(numeroUsuario == 0){
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor difernete a 0.')
  }
  
  else {
  if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
   modulo = 'par';
   alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
  } else {
   modulo = 'impar';
   alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
  }
 }
}
```

Respuesta con la ayuda de [Peter Olson](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/416/peter-olson)

Comment: Muchas gracias, otra pregunta=>
Obviamente no puedo parsear al principio ya que si hago numeroUsuario = Number(prompt('Introduce un numero')); => Luego no podre manejar el null verdad? 
Otra cosa, hay alguna manera mas corta de hacer todo esto? En lugar de (Number(!numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '' || numeroUsuario == 0)
Quieroese orden, que si es null lo diga y si son estas 3 opciones lo diga, solo esta esta manera pues no?
Mil gracias

Comment: Otra cosa, porque si hago => (Number(!numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '' || parseInt(numeroUsuario == '0')) NO ME FUNCIONA TAMPOCO? estoy convirtiendo a numero el string '0' deberia funcionar igual pero si funciona => Number(numeroUsuario == '0'). PORQUE NO parseint pero si number

Comment: lo acomode revisa a ver si es lo que necesitas y algún cambio que requieras

Comment: PERO luis,  solo con !numeroUsuario ya estoy diciendo que todo lo que sea 0, '' null undefined(falsey values), y como es ! digo que  en este caso si doy a ok es '' y ahi sera true, entonces no hace falta poner numeroUsuario === '' si ya he puesto !numeroUsuario cierto?

Comment: Otra cosa mas luis, puedes ver mi codigo de nuevo, esta bien asi o estaria mejor de otra manera mas corta y simplificada? Ya lo edite. Mil gracias